# How can I create several butterfly diagrams at once in Understand?

Tags: dependencies, scitools

## Background

In the "Show Graphic Views" menu of [Understand](https://scitools.com/features/), there is the option to create a [butterfly graph](https://scitools.com/support/butterfly-graph-key/), for one specific entity as seen below:

[image]

In addition, there is the [und command](https://scitools.com/support/commandline/) as well. This command has the capability of running commands in a batch in the following way:

> Once you have identified the commands you want to run using interactive mode,  place those exact commands in a text file. No need to include the first und command or the quit command, those are handled automatically.
>
> Then all you have to do is run
>
> und myCommands.txt

I have over 1000 c++ classes that I want to create butterfly diagrams for. Given the automation capability of the und command, and the ability for understand to create butterfly diagrams for various entities I wanted to know....

## Question

Is there a way for Understand to automate the creation of butterfly diagrams?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.  I never heard of the "Understand" tool before.  It looks very cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can script this using perl or Python...
Open the tool, and check out the top menu, Help >> Perl API or Help >> Python API... There is a help on the API
They show an example like this (create the "callby" graph for all the funcions...), just change it to butterfly.

```
import understand
db = understand.open("test.udb")
for func in db.ents("function,method,procedure"):
  file = "callby_" + func.name() + ".png"
  print (func.longname(),"->",file)
  func.draw("Called By",file)
```